# jQuery extract finishing part of the domain (.com, .it, .fr) from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, extract

I have an issue where I have a domain like this:

```
https://example.com/Controller/Index
```

or:

```
https://example.it/Controller/Index
```

or:

```
https://example.de/Controller/Index
```

I would like to extract the .com .de and .it part of the domain by using jQuery. I looked around and I haven't found any example on how to do it.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: This might help you get started https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

Comment: @SurajJadhav I got it like this: split('.')[2].split('/')[0] ... Is this the best solution or there's easier way?

Comment: As long the signature of the string you mentioned remains the same and if this solution is serving your purpose it can be termed as the best solution for now. :)

Comment: @SurajJadhav Yes it's gonna remain same :D

Comment: To make it more readable,  
`var str = "https://example.it/Controller/Index";`
`str.match('https://example(.*)/Controller/Index')[1];`

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I would like to extract the .com .de and .it part of the domain" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply trying to parse the URL of the page itself, you can simply check `window.location.hostname`. You simply split it by the `.` character and obtain the last item:

```
var hostnameParts = window.location.hostname.split('.');
var topLevelDomain = hostnameParts[hostnameParts.length - 1];
```

```js
var hostnameParts = window.location.hostname.split('.');
var topLevelDomain = hostnameParts[hostnameParts.length - 1];

console.log('This iframe\'s hostname: ' + window.location.hostname);
console.log('The top level domain: ' + topLevelDomain);
```

---

However, if you are going to parse the URL when it is present in a string, then you will need to rely on regex:

```
var url = 'https://example.com/Controller/Index';
var pattern = /^https?:\/\/.*\.(.*?)\/.*$/gi;
var urlParsed = pattern.exec(url);
var topLevelDomain = urlParsed ? urlParsed[1] : null;
```

Proof-of-concept example:

```js
document.getElementById('parseUrl').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
  var pattern = /^https?:\/\/.*\.(.*?)\/.*$/gi;
  var urlParsed = pattern.exec(url);
  console.log('Parsing URL string: ' + url);

  if (urlParsed) {
    console.log('- Top level domain: ' + urlParsed[1]);
  } else {
    console.log('- Unable to parse URL');
  }
});
```

```css
#url {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="https://example.com/Controller/Index" id="url" />
<button type="button" id="parseUrl">Get top level domain</button>
```